# How can I get object from parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserView");

    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", id);

    List<ParseObject> parseObjects = query.find();

    if (parseObjects.size() == 0)
        status = true;
    else {
        status = false;
        for (ParseObject object : parseObjects) {
            String name= object.get("name").toString();
        }
    }
    return status;
```

I want to get my object equal to Id. All data come along with state column but I cannot reach of them. [image: image1]

Comment: You should be using `findInBackground` if you are on android - https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries

Comment: Well, according to that picture you are querying where objectId is null, so you should fix where you assign the value of `id` in your Java code

Comment: Then your question is still not very clear to me.

Comment: I see at debug mode what I send objectId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", id);
```

Instead of

```
query.whereEqualTo("id", id);
```

And also the user data are in `state` key, so try something like:

```
String name = object.getParseObject("state").get("name").toString();
```

Comment: I try but same problem . data has comed but I cannot reach them

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: all data inside state column not UserView object

Comment: @gurkankeskin try object.get("state"), does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserView");
ParseObject parseObject = query.get(id);
```